# Table and caption output after footnote in Latex - how to make sure footnote is always at bottom of the page?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabu

I'm using:

```
\begin{table}
{\tabulinesep = 1.2mm
\begin{tabu}{c || c | c | c | c}
species & Ar & Kr & $\SI{}{N_2}$ & $\SI{}{CO_2}$\\ \hline
$I_p$ & \SI{15.76}{eV} & \SI{14.00}{eV} & \SI{15.58}{eV} & \SI{13.78}{eV}\\
\end{tabu}}
\caption{caption text}
\label{tab:Ip}
\end{table}\\
```

to typeset the table shown in the screenshot linked below. The table and the caption show up below a footnote. I tried moving the table environment to a position before the footnote in latex but it still appears after the footnote.

I'm using TeXnicCenter 1.0 and LaTeX => PDF (Sumatra) to create the output.

How can I make sure a footnote is always the last thing to appear on a page?
Thanks for your help!

[Screenshot of page with table and caption after footnote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j97Y.jpg)

Comment: As an aside, you have `{\tabulinesep = 1.2mm ... \end{tabu}}` but the effect of changing `\tabulinesep` is localized by the outer `table` environment. So you don't need those explicit curly braces.

Comment: Thank you @yudai-nkt, I somehow wasn't able to find the other post you linked, which solved the problem. Also thanks for the aside, much appreciated!